# Collecting List<Long> results from RecursiveTask of a ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, recursion, primes, fork-join

we need to split a prime factor calculation into multiple recursive tasks in a forkjoinpool.

We've got a List of prime numbers and a workloadSize, like 5.
So if we want to calculate the primefactors for 50, we get all prime numbers to 25 and calculate the primefactors. The workloadSize is the amount of prime numbers a single recursive task will handle.

What Ive done:

```
Long[] workLoad = new Long[primes.size()];
workLoad = primes.toArray(workLoad);

pool = new ForkJoinPool();
ForkJoinWorker worker = new ForkJoinWorker(workLoad, q, partitionSize, 0);
pool.execute(worker);

resultList =  worker.invoke();
```

workLoad = array of all prime numbers.

q = the number we want to calc the prime factors for.

ForkJoinWorker extends a RecursiveTask>

Inside the Recursive task I look if the workLoadSize is greater than the array of primes Ive got, if it is, I create a new

```
ForkJoinWorker f = new ForkJoinWorker(..);
f.fork();
List<Long> results = calcFactors(...);
results.addAll(f.join);
return results;
```

Did I just getting something completly wrong? I always get a concurrent exception and stack overflow. I think I dont connect the recursive tasks correctly, because it allways causes stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

A complete stacktrace, and a more complete code sample should help clarify what's going on. But Several things stick out in the code you've shown.

### Invoking the main task

In you sample, you do

```
pool.execute(worker);
resultList =  worker.invoke();
```

Which is not the way it's supposed to work.

Calling "execute" dispatches the task, which is fine, but it will not wait for it's completion. So you have just launched a computation, with no handle at its completion or result.

Calling `invoke` yourself is not something you would do normally, you should let the `pool` invoke this method itself. Because it will start the execution of the task, in the calling thread, with no support from any pool. So you may even deadlock yourself if you `join` in an illogic order.

The "intended" way for you to invoke a `RecursiveTask<T>` is by calling `pool.invoke(task)`, which will return you a `T` (the result of the computation) or `pool.submit(task)` which will return you a `Future`.

### Sharing state between the tasks

This piece of code inside a task can be problematic :

```
List<Long> results = calcFactors(...);
results.addAll(f.join);
```

It will work if `calcFactors` creates its own `List` to return. But if this list is shared among tasks, it means that multiple tasks (and threads) may perform `addAll` on the same instance, which will only work if the list is able to support it (I think the only concurrent `List` in the JDK is the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`).